# How does the bus fare payment work in Israel?

Tags: public-transport, buses, loyalty-programs, israel

I try to find prices for intercity buses in Israel, but I always get to a website of a company representative (Egged Transport) with huge tables of stops.

Is there a way to calculate an exact cost of a trip? Are there any pitfalls, traveling with no loyalty card like Rav Card? Is it certain, that the cost up to 20 shekels can not be paid by debit card?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Egged's English site](https://mslworld.egged.co.il/?language=en&state=) isn't pretty, but contains the prices. Choose origin and destination, search, then click "trip summary" to see the price.

However, Egged is not the only inter-city bus operator in Israel. Other operators, like Kavim and Metropolin have even worse sites, and in Hebrew only.

Paying small sums in credit is uncommon in Israel, often cards (credit/debit usually doesn't matter) are refused under 30 shekels. Paying with a card on a bus is also unusual.

I think there are two options:

1. Pay cash.
2. Buy a Rav-Kav for 5 shekels and charge it. It may be difficult to know how much to charge, or to get refunded for remaining credit.

Comment: Is there a different fee for a few stops or you pay once for the whole ride?

Comment: @chzzh You pay for the whole ride. On a city bus, you pay for an hour and a half, so you can change buses on the same ticket. If you get a Rav-Kav, you can also charge it with a day ticket for a particular area (e.g Jerusalem) and travel by any and all public transportation within that area. For example, a day ticket that includes all the country except the lines to Eilat will cost you 65 shekels, if I remember correctly. It includes trains, inter-city buses, city buses and the light rail in Jerusalem.

Comment: I think the rules may have changed recently. I don’t think cash is accepted everywhere and busses stopped selling the RavKav. Check the website for most current information.

Comment: @LN6595, you can still buy a Rav Kav from the driver, charged with a single ride, for the cost of that ride plus 5 shekels, and pay cash.